# NodeJS pretty console for displaying objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, logging, console

I am dealing with pretty large objects with NodeJS that I would like to look at. Currently, I am using window's command prompt and util.inpsect to display my objects. However, the object comes out looking something like this: 
{
    foo: 'bar',
    doo: 'dar',
    yoo: 'yar',
    who: 'harhar',
    longer: { 
 short1: 'doodar', 
 short2: 'heehar' 
 }
}

I would like a console similar to chrome's console, where I can collapse parts of the object (with the arrows on the side). I don't want to download a whole environment either, just the console part.

[image: Picture]

Also, I would like to display things to this console with console.log, so https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal-kit wouldn't work

Comment: @DanStarns I can print the object out, but I want to collapse branches. Converting it to JSON doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @DanStarns That is what it already looks like

Comment: You can use chrome dev tools, real easy to set up > https://flaviocopes.com/node-debug-devtools/